# Resettable fuse nominal

Tags: fuses

I've found a part which looks like this:

[image: Polyswitch Fuses MiniSMD series]

I found out that this is a fuse, but i can't find any information about nominal. I suppose that marking show allowed current, but what about multiplier?

Comment: have you googled for the product description in the file name of your picture? Because that instantly drops me to a page with links to datasheets.

Comment: I did. But i don't get what the second "2" means. Is it just for convenience, so you can read it in any position?

Comment: Why does it have to "mean" something? It's really just a symbol, like Marcus doesn't "mean" anything, but is just a name for this particular human! Clicking through a full **three** datasheet shows it is [this](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/product_specifications/resettable_ptcs/littelfuse_ptc_minismdc020f_2_product_specification.pdf.pdf) device.

Comment: Resistors markings "mean" their resistance, so i thought the same applies there. I viewed about 10 of datasheets and didn't find anything similar to this markings. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply the same thing upside-down, as you can see in [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/73f8/0900766b8142b8bf.pdf) datasheet (similar datasheet linked in  @Marcus Müller's comment).

[image]